# Set UpdatedTimeStamp in a particular TimeZone in Spring Boot Hibernate for Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity that stores a last updated date like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "counter")
public class Count {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uniq_id")
    String uniqId;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    int amount;

    @Column(name = "points")
    double points;

    @Column(name = "handshake")
    boolean handshake;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    Date timestamp;

    //getter setters
}
```

This part

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "updated_date")
Date timestamp;
```

means that whenever this entity is used, the `timestamp` is auto updated and persisted on the database.

Now my problem is, how do I set this `timestamp` automatically on a specific TimeZone? I am using Postgresql. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A `Date` hasn't got a time zone, so this may not be possible. What is the datatype in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @OleV.V. The column is being created like this `timestamp without time zone` in Postgresql

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), JPA supports the java-8 date classes, so use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to map `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

[Mapping Java 8 Date Types](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time#after-java-8)

```
@Column(name = "updated_date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
 private OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime;
```

For `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` you can use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

```
@Column(name = "updated_date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```